# Set ignored tags from their popup

Tags: support, tags

Hovering on a tag allows us to subscribe to it or see the RSS feed.  Can we also have a link in there to ignore it?  That would make it much more efficient to filter a view (e.g. unanswered) for only questions that I'm able to answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This feature already exists. Just click the star until it changes to a red X.

(The "subscribe" link turns on *email* notifications, which is probably not what you want.)

Comment: Much appreciated. It could be a little more obvious, but I'm glad the functionality is already there. :-)

Comment: Hover your mouse over the star, and wait a moment.

Comment: I guess if I'd thought about it for a while I would have realised that the star wasn't just there for decoration, but it would be more intuitive IMO if there were separate favourite and ignore buttons.

Comment: And on an unrelated note, having a minimum wait time for accepting an answer is also a little annoying.  I've tried to click that tick 3 times already! :-)